# React route syntax

Tags: reactjs

In React routing example, I have seen syntax like below;

```
<Route exact path = '/' render = {() => Homepage} />
```

But was just wondering if this is also valid i.e. `<Homepage />`;

```
<Route exact path = '/' render = {() => <Homepage />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid syntax.  The first requires you set the `Homepage` variable to an instance of a component prior to using it in the route.  Failure to do so would lead to a runtime exception.  In the first example you could assign an instance of any component to the `Homepage` variable whereas the second syntax always passes an instance of the specific `Homepage` component.  If you want to dynamically choose which component to render for the route you would want to use the first but if your route is static either would work.

Comment: Thanks. So the complete example is on https://medium.com/better-programming/react-router-whats-the-difference-between-components-and-routes-d242f41b111d

So for first case, when you say "set the Homepage variable to an instance of a component". Do you mean like how they have imported it OR it can be via some other way as well ? 
import 'Homepage' from './Home';

Comment: Whatever way that creates an instance of a component and stores it in that variable name.  There are several ways to do it.